# Where does the debug panel in Laravel store the query history?

Tags: laravel

I can't figure out where the request history for the debug panel is stored.  It seems that there is no separate table in the database for this. And it seems that there are no separate requests for backing

Comment: If you're talking about the [laravel debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) there should be a folder under storage with json files that have the collector data (that's the default). You can also configure where the storage goes via the `config/debugbar.php` file if you've published that

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what package you're referring to but the functionality you describe doesn't really need to store anything. If I were to guess, it registers a `ServiceProvider` that adds a Listener for Query Events.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/database#listening-for-query-events

If you want to try it out, you can do it in a tinker session.

```php
DB::listen(fn ($q) => dump([$q->sql, $q->bindings, $q->time]));

User::first();

// Will dump ['select * from users limit 1', [], 'xxxms']
```

As for the Request information, it can be accessed at any time with `request()`.